# Summing numbers with header in Python

Tags: python, sum

I have to write a script that does this:

Inputfile:
Name
10
-43
54
Name2
654
43
2
-5467
Name3
65
65

Outputfile:
Name 21
Name2 -4768
Name3 130

I came to the conclusion that I am supposed to split the input into arrays at the names and then print the first element and the sum of the rest, but I do not know how to do it and I haven't really found anything about this on the web.

Comment: Read the input linewise; try to cast each line to a number, and if that succeeds you know you have a new number for a current header, if it doesn't work (an exception is raised), you know that you have a new header and the summing is finished for the last one. Does this outline help?

Comment: [Reading and writing files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some hints:

```
>>> int('Name1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Name1'
>>> int('-43')
-43
```

That should help you figure out what is a string and what not. It will also convert your input to a number for you.

Find out how to catch errors (`try`, `except`).

Find out how to read a file line by line. Try iterating over the file ;)

The rest is basic programming logic. Figuring it out yourself will give you most bang for the buck.

Answer (score 1):

Open the files and use readline to open the files line by line. Check whether it is string or not. By looking at your file format, I assume everything in between two strings (Name1 and Name2 or else) are numbers so store those on list. Finally use sum(list) to get the output. I am not writing the code since this is "HOMEWORK".

Comment: Don't use `readline()`. You can iterate over the file directly.

Comment: I wrote it to give the demonstration. After all, using readline and some loop due to using readline won't hurt for 'homework'.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the file line by line using

```
for line in open('test.txt'):
    # do stuff
```

When you find a name you need to start adding each number to a sum until you encounter until you find a different name when you start to sum the numbers again from zero.